# Google Place API cities list with proper names/nomenclature

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to crate an auto complete feature which shows list of cities in US as the user types in the data. They can then select multiple locations as they see fit.

I got the google place API and am able to use it. However, what I am trying to get to is use nomenclature like "silicon valley" to enable automatic selection of cities within that region. For e.g. When user types in DMV, the system should recognize multiple cities within the DMV region.

Any help on how I can do it?

Really appreciate your feedback

Just used Google API for Places, but need to see if I can get regions (like Silicon Valley, DMV etc)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase the probability that you get help from the community.